# How to access drop-down option in Chakra UI using puppeteer Library?

Tags: reactjs, automation, puppeteer, browser-automation, chakra-ui

I can see the following HTML code for the following Button that correspond to drop-down menu

```
<button class="flex cursor-pointer items-center rounded text-left focus:outline-none whitespace-nowrap text-label-2 dark:text-dark-label-2 bg-transparent dark:bg-dark-transparent hover:bg-transparent dark:hover:bg-transparent hover:text-label-1 dark:hover:text-dark-label-1 active:bg-transparent dark:active:bg-dark-transparent ml-2 px-2 py-1.5 pr-1 font-medium text-xs group" id="headlessui-listbox-button-:r1d:" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-headlessui-state=""><div class="flex items-center"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="4 4 16 16" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" class="text-gray-6 dark:text-dark-gray-6 group-hover:text-gray-7 dark:group-hover:text-dark-gray-7 h-4 w-4"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.741 7.314a.95.95 0 00-.627-.272.95.95 0 00-.627.272.833.833 0 00-.246.614c0 .246.082.45.246.614a.85.85 0 00.627.245.85.85 0 00.627-.245.833.833 0 00.246-.614.832.832 0 00-.246-.614zm-.34 2.919c-.01-.273-.178-.41-.505-.41-.4.092-.914.36-1.541.805-.628.446-.969.696-1.023.75-.055.055-.082.091-.082.11l.082.136c.036.09.063.14.082.15.018.01.054-.004.109-.04l.627-.41c.564-.364.732-.16.505.614-.228.772-.505 1.94-.832 3.505-.055.709.127 1.013.545.913.419-.1.746-.231.982-.395l1.364-.955c.055-.036.073-.072.055-.109l-.11-.19c-.036-.037-.072-.055-.109-.055l-.027.027c-.218.145-.45.29-.695.436-.246.146-.405.146-.478 0-.036-.218.064-.754.3-1.609l.682-2.564c.055-.2.077-.436.068-.71z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg><div>C++</div></div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" class="pointer-events-none ml-2 w-3 h-3 text-gray-6 dark:text-dark-gray-6 group-hover:text-gray-7 dark:group-hover:text-dark-gray-7" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.929 7.913l7.078 7.057 7.064-7.057a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-7.77 7.764a1 1 0 01-1.415 0L3.515 9.328a1 1 0 011.414-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></button>
```

Is there any function that can help to select any options from drop-down ?

I have tried using select() that puppeteer provides.
I have tried clicking the button (page.click()) and keyboard.press('enter')

no method so far has been successfull.